# vb6: interrupt endless msgbox loop

Tags: vb6, infinite-loop

I am writing a program in VB6.

By mistake many times my code contains an endless loop, inside which there is a message box. For example:

```
while a>0
    msgbox "a is positive"
wend
```

Then I press the play/run and I realize what has happened. Is there any way to stop the debugging/running of my program?

The only thing that works so far is **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>** and end task. But this way the whole visual basic closes and I lose my unsaved data. (please don't comment that I should save my program more often. I know it (now)).

Edit: I found on the internet that maybe **<kbd>esc</kbd>** or **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>** or **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>break</kbd>** could do the job. The first two do nothing and my laptop doesn't have a break key

**Solution**: I have the **<kbd>insert</kbd>** key in my laptop. on the key there is also written `pause` for use along with the **<kbd>Fn</kbd>** key. So I was able to break the application by pressing **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>** (which maybe could be translated in **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>**)

edit: link to [photo of my keyboard](http://content.hwigroup.net/images/products/xl/173256/3/dell_latitude_e5430_54301864.jpg):

Answer (score 23):

`ctrl` + `break` will work.  If you don't have those keys, use the on screen keyboard.

Start | Run | osk

Then press `ctrl` + `break`.

Comment: thanks for that "other way". I couldn't find the break in the osk either. however i solved my problem. i'm editing my question

Comment: @ThanosDarkadakis, with the on screen keyboard for Win7, `ctrl` + `pause` should get you a break.

Comment: If you also don't have OSK for some reason you can use `SendKeys` from PowerShell for example: `[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms"); sleep 1; [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{BREAK}")`  (type in PowerShell) Reference: [1](https://www.jesusninoc.com/11/05/simulate-key-press-by-user-with-sendkeys-and-powershell/) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791783/powershell-unable-to-find-type-system-windows-forms-keyeventhandler)